# How can i change my ip addres

Tags: relays, ip-address

I tried: new circuit, new identity, set "ExitNodes {US}" and restart tor

my ip address always remains the same.

Comment: How are you checking your IP address?

Comment: There is a site that still saying that my ip is banned, and the ip shown is always the same

Answer (score 0):

All you've missed is `StrictNodes 1` option - it tells Tor that it has to enforce the nodes to be on your ExitNodes list. New identity helps to circle through them

Comment: No, StrictNodes does nothing when it comes to ExitNodes https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#StrictNodes

Comment: I've just tried it myself again - and it gives US only nodes with both ExitNodes and StrictNodes. I used to meet this odd behavior from time to time, but - **yes**, without it ExitNodes can be missing an exit country much more times than a GeoIP bias, even with a paid GeoIP database - it gives a way more precise work, by the way